# Change Font Size in Table instead of the \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!} command

Tags: tables, fontsize, changes

I'm creating a table for my thesis but when I'm compiling it, it shrinks because of the \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!} command. I would like to know if I could make the font size bigger without making the table overpass the page limits. Here's how I created my table:

```
\begin{table}[]
\caption{Sujetos de Información}
\label{tab:my-table}
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{|cclll|}
        \hline
        \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Sujetos de Información} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Rol} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Cantidad} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Responsabilidades} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Relación al Proyecto} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Información Brindada} \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Jefe del Área Técnica} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Distribuye a los mecánicos según las necesidades de cada área para que las máquinas\\ puedan ser atendidas y reparadas dentro de los tiempos esperados.\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Brindar información y ayuda para la\\ mejora y rediseño del sistema\\ mecánico del módulo de inspección\\ de la máquina\end{tabular}} &  \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Técnicos Mecánicos} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{10} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Encargados de realizar mantenimientos correctivos y preventivos a las máquinas de cada\\ una de las áreas, los cuales deben de ejecutarse en un tiempo establecido según la máquina.\\ También pueden reportar problemas de mayor dificultad a los superiores para el arreglo de la\\ máquina.\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Interesados Directos de la Solución.} &  \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Gerente de Ingeniería Mainstream} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Encargado del área de ingeniería mecánica de las máquinas para conectores. Realiza la \\ administración de proyectos y tareas relacionadas a las mejores o cambios mecánicos \\ que deban ser realizados a las máquinas.\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Brindar información y ayuda para la\\ mejora y rediseño del sistema\\ mecánico del módulo de inspección\\ de la máquina\end{tabular}} &  \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Gerente de Ingeniería Eléctrica} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Encargado de la automatización de la empresa. Analiza mejoras y actualizaciones que pueden\\ ser implementadas en las máquinas, analizando la parte lógica de la máquina y los \\ componentes y dispositivos de control y potencia.\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Brindar información y ayuda para la\\ mejora y rediseño del sistema\\ mecánico del módulo de inspección\\ de la máquina\end{tabular}} &  \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Técnicos Eléctricos} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{3} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Encargados de la automatización en el campo como cableado y conectividad de equipos.\\ Proporcionan mantenimiento y atienden las averías en toda la empresa.\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Interesados Directos de la Solución.} &  \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Gerente de Producción} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Encargado de la producción de la empresa. Se encarga de comprobar que la productividad \\ se encuentre en los valores esperados y no caigan.\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Interesados Directos de la Solución.} &  \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Supervisor de Automation} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{1} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Encargado del área de Automation. Administra los operarios del área para que trabajen\\ según las órdenes de alta, media y baja prioridad, asignándolos a las diferentes máquinas\\ según corresponda.\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Interesados Directos de la Solución.} &  \\ \hline
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Operarios de Automation} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{30} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Operarios del área de Automation. Recargan las máquinas con los bodies plásticos para los \\ componentes, verifican medidas críticas del componente, reparan fallas leves de la máquina\\ y reportan averías mayores de la misma.\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Interesados Directos de la Solución.} &  \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}%
}
```

\end{table}

Thanks for the help

Comment: Please tell us more about your document setup. E.g., which document class do you employ? Does your document employ a two-column layout? What's the main document font size?

Comment: never use `\resizebox` on tables, as you show here the result is likely to be ugly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to change the font size. Instead, I suggest you switch from `tabular` to [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) to enable automatic line breaking in the cells. And, do make columns 3 and 4 wider than columns 1, 2, and 5.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} % or some other suitable document class

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters appropriately
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{tabularx} % for 'tabularx' env. and 'X' col. type
\usepackage{ragged2e} % for '\RaggedRight' and '\Centering' macros
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\hsize=#1\hsize\Centering\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for well-spaced horizontal rules

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt} % default: 6pt
\caption{Sujetos de Información\strut}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{} L{0.65} C{0.4} L{2} L{1.3} L{0.65} @{}}
% Note: 0.65+0.4+2+1.3+0.65 = 5 = # of X-type columns
\toprule
%\multicolumn{5}{c}{Sujetos de Información} \\ 
%\addlinespace % \hline
Rol & Cantidad & Responsabilidades 
& Relación al Proyecto & Información Brindada \\ 
\midrule
Jefe del Área Técnica & 1 
& Distribuye a los mecánicos según las necesidades de cada área para que las máquinas puedan ser atendidas y reparadas dentro de los tiempos esperados. 
& Brindar información y ayuda para la mejora y rediseño del sistema mecánico del módulo de inspección de la máquina 
& \\ \addlinespace % \hline
Técnicos Mecánicos & 10 
& Encargados de realizar mantenimientos correctivos y preventivos a las máquinas de cada una de las áreas, los cuales deben de ejecutarse en un tiempo establecido según la máquina. También pueden reportar problemas de mayor dificultad a los superiores para el arreglo de la máquina.
& Interesados Directos de la Solución. 
& \\ \addlinespace % \hline
Gerente de Ingeniería Mainstream & 1 
& Encargado del área de ingeniería mecánica de las máquinas para conectores. Realiza la administración de proyectos y tareas relacionadas a las mejores o cambios mecánicos que deban ser realizados a las máquinas. 
& Brindar información y ayuda para la mejora y rediseño del sistema mecánico del módulo de inspección de la máquina 
& \\ \addlinespace % \hline
Gerente de Ingeniería Eléctrica & 1 
& Encargado de la automatización de la empresa. Analiza mejoras y actualizaciones que pueden ser implementadas en las máquinas, analizando la parte lógica de la máquina y los componentes y dispositivos de control y potencia.
& Brindar información y ayuda para la mejora y rediseño del sistema mecánico del módulo de inspección de la máquina 
& \\ \addlinespace % \hline
Técnicos Eléctricos & 3 
& Encargados de la automatización en el campo como cableado y conectividad de equipos. Proporcionan mantenimiento y atienden las averías en toda la empresa.
& Interesados Directos de la Solución. 
& \\ \addlinespace % \hline
Gerente de Producción & 1 
& Encargado de la producción de la empresa. Se encarga de comprobar que la productividad  se encuentre en los valores esperados y no caigan.
& Interesados Directos de la Solución. 
& \\ \addlinespace % \hline
Supervisor de Automation & 1 
& Encargado del área de Automation. Administra los operarios del área para que trabajen según las órdenes de alta, media y baja prioridad, asignándolos a las diferentes máquinas según corresponda.
& Interesados Directos de la Solución. 
& \\ \addlinespace % \hline
Operarios de Automation & 30 
& Operarios del área de Automation. Recargan las máquinas con los bodies plásticos para los componentes, verifican medidas críticas del componente, reparan fallas leves de la máquina y reportan averías mayores de la misma. 
& Interesados Directos de la Solución. 
& \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```